# HK a subgroup, neither is included in the other's normalizer?

Tags: group-theory

Can anyone think of an example of the following: $H$ and $K$ are proper subgroups of $G$.  $H$ is not contained in the normalizer of $K$. $K$ is not contained in the normalizer of $H$. Nevertheless, $HK$, the set of all $hk$ where $h \in H$, and $k \in K$, is somehow a group?

Comment: $HK$ is a group if and only if $HK=KH$

Answer (score 6):

Consider $G = S_{4}$, of order $24$.

Let $H$ be a $2$-Sylow subgroup, of order $8$, and $K$ a $3$-Sylow subgroup, of order $3$.

Then $HK= G$ is a subgroup of $G$. This is because of the formula for the product of two subgroups
$$
\lvert H K \rvert = \frac{\lvert H \rvert \cdot \lvert K \rvert}{\lvert H \cap K \rvert}.
$$

However, neither $H$ normalizes $K$, nor $K$ normalizes $H$.

To see this, note that if were the case that $H$ normalizes $K$, then $K$ would be normal in $G$, thus unique, so that $G$ would have only two elements of order $3$. However $G$ has many (actually $8$) elements of order $3$.

A similar argument (there are $2$ elements of order $4$ in the dihedral group $H$, while $G$ has $6$) shows that $K$ does not normalize $H$.

Comment: Didn't he require $H$ not be CONTAINED in the normalizer of $K$ and vice versa? It's not clear to me that what you did was equivalent.

Comment: To say that $H$ (does not) normalize(s)  $K$ is exactly the same thing as to say that $H$ is (not) contained in the normalizer of $K$.

Comment: It might be more interesting to require that $HK$ is a proper subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @Stefanos, take the very same $H$ and $K$, but regarded as subgroups of $S_{5}$.

Answer (score 2):

To generalize the example given by Andreas, let $G$ be a finite group of order $p^a q^b$, where $p \neq q$ are primes. Suppose that $G$ does not have a normal Sylow subgroup. The $G$ contains the following example.

Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup and $Q$ a Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G$. Now $Q$ does not normalize $P$ since otherwise $P$ would be normal. Similarly $P$ does not normalize $Q$. However, $G = PQ$ since $PQ$ has same order as $G$.